# Sublime Text Flake8 lint error on Mechanize which does not appear when running flake8 by hand

Tags: python, sublimetext2, mechanize, pyflakes, flake8

I use `mechanize` library for a small python project.

Why does Sublime Text 2 (with [Flake8Lint](https://github.com/dreadatour/Flake8Lint)) shows me that there is no such member `select_form()` in browser.
I have checked _mechanize.py and there it is.

Also why it can find `open()` member?

I import mechanize with simple:

`import mechanize`

Here is what I get:

[image]

Comment: It's has nothing to do with the mechanize or Flake8 itself. If you run flake8 on the actual file, it won't give you any errors(regarding mechanize import). Try `from mechanize import Browser`

Comment: Yes, there is no error when I run `flake8.py` directly on file.

Comment: I have also tried `from mechanize import Browser` but with no results.